# Cross Compiling, Crosstool, Makefile , libreadline

Tags: c, linux, makefile, cross-compiling, crosstool-ng

I am using Simplicity Studio to generate code for my application. It auto generates a Makefile and I am able to build application that runs on my host pc amd64 ubuntu 16.02.

Now I want to build the application so it will work in Raspberry Pi. So I installed crostool-ng and also Rpi crosstool. Now I don't know much about make files but I did `make CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` instead of `make`.

It fails at

> fatal error: readline/readline.h: No such file or directory

I have already installed **libreadline-dev** and also **libreadline-dev** for armhf.

Am I doing this the right way ? Do I need to make some other changes ?

I have not worked on big projects before and I am very bad at understanding makefiles.

I have compiled simple C programs for Pi and they work.

[makefile](https://github.com/EbadSyed/GatewayHostApp/blob/master/Z3GatewayHost_2/Makefile)

[Application code and makefile](https://github.com/EbadSyed/GatewayHostApp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe is the variable CROSS_COMPILE what you need.

The toolchain is not only the compiler. They are even basic bin utils needed for the whole build process.

Try this instead:

```
make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```